# Moq multi interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, mocking, moq

**Background:**

I have spun up a simple Proxy thing for my Wcf client based partly on examples found online and partly on my needs.

The usage for creating a client proxy as its known is:

```
WcfClientProxy<IServicecontract> clientProxy = 
                                 new WcfClientProxy<IServiceContract>();
```

WcfClientProxy has a method called Execute which takes  : `Expression<Func<TChannel, TResult>>` or `Expression<Action<TChannel>>`.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I am trying to mock this using Moq so I can test the calls made to the service contract via the client.

So mock a call like this..

```
clientProxy.Execute(m=>m.DoSomeAction(5));
```

**The problem:**

The problem is that the mock does not work. I get this error:

" threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

My test service contract is:

```
public interface ITestingServiceInterface : System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
    string Version();
    VersionDetail VersionDetail();
    IList<VersionDetail> VersionDetails();
    void DoSomeDelete(int itemId);
}
```

The wcf client proxy interface:

```
public interface IWcfClientProxy<TChannel> where TChannel : ICommunicationObject
{
    bool ThrowOnException { get; set; }
    TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression<Func<TChannel, TResult>> operation);
    void Execute(Expression<Action<TChannel>> expression);
}
```

My attempted test and mock with setup..

```
private List<ProdItem> items;
private Mock<IWcfClientProxy<ITestingServiceInterface>> mockClientProxy;

[TestInitialize]
public void SettingUp()
{
    mockClientProxy = new Mock<IWcfClientProxy<ITestingServiceInterface>>();

    items = new List<ProdItem>();
    for( int i =0; i<10; i++){
        items.Add(new ProdItem { ProdItemId = i, LocalStock = i });
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    mockClientProxy.Setup(m => m.Execute(x => x.DoSomeDelete(It.IsAny<int>()))).Callback(RemoveItem);

    var client = mockClientProxy.Object;

    client.Execute(x => x.DoSomeDelete(4));

    Assert.AreEqual(9, items.Count);
}

public void RemoveItem()
{
    items.RemoveAt(items.Count - 1);
}
```

The error for this test is actually that the assert is wrong, it seems like the Callback is never being hit.

I'm sure I have just done something stupid.

**Update:**
Showing an example of what I would like to be able to test if the above worked..

```
[TestMethod]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    mockClientProxy.Setup(m => m.Execute(x => x.DoSomeDelete(It.IsAny<int>()))).Callback(RemoveItem);

    var client = mockClientProxy.Object;

    var stockHelper = new StockHelper(client);

    stockHelper.DeleteItem(5);

    Assert.AreEqual(9, items.Count);
}
```

In the above I am testing the StockHelper Class that take a client proxy in its constructor through which it does its calls to WCF.

To test the StockHelper (or what ever) I need to be able to mock the client and its service calls. The above (1st) example demon-straights me having an issue trying to do this.

I hope that makes sense, please see that my end goal is not to test a mock.. that is just where I have got to trying to debug my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see from your code, you are testing mock. I don't see any real object you are testing. Mocks are used to stub dependencies of objects being tested. So, if some class `Foo` uses `IWcfClientProxy` then you provide mock of this proxy to class `Foo`. And verify that during `Foo.Bar()` execution method `DoSomeDelete` of dependency was called. That's the purpose of mocks.

```
[TestClass]
public class FooTests
{
   private Foo _foo;
   private Mock<IWcfClientProxy<ITestingServiceInterface>> _clientProxy;

   [TestInitialize]
   public void SettingUp()
   {
       _clientProxy = new Mock<IWcfClientProxy<ITestingServiceInterface>>();
       _foo = new Foo(_clientProxy.Object);
   }

   [TestMethod]
   public void SimpleTest()
   {
       // Act on object being tested
       _foo.Bar(5);

       // verify it executed correct method on dependency
       _clientProxy.Verify(cp => cp.Execute(x => x.DoSomeDelete(5)));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, when testing `Foo` you should not care how `_clientProxy` is implemented.

Comment: The client proxy would generally be passed to something, say a helper class. then the tests would be to test the helper class rather than the proxy, but because I cant test the proxy at the moment I have not shown that as an example. If I pass no parameters to the service method it works as expected.

Comment: I have updated the question, (just seen your updated answer) Do I need to be using the Verify rather than setting up Returns and Callbacks? would that be my issue?

Comment: Proxy has method `Execute`. So you need to verify that this method was called with right parameters. If needed you can provide some fake return value for mocked method. (sorry lunch time, will be back in a hour) :)

Comment: Tried that, it complains that the method is never called.

Comment: If you want to setup any action as Execute parameter, use `_clientProxy.Setup(cp => cp.Execute(It.IsAny<Expression<Action<ITestingServiceInterface>>>()))//.Callback()`

Comment: Btw if you want to check exact expression parameter match, I don't think it is possible with moq: http://groups.google.com/group/moqdisc/browse_thread/thread/20f5a2ceefcba0e/8f477c1f5c4b5321?lnk=gst&q=func&pli=1

Comment: The problem has something to do with the above link. This means that I cant mock individual method calls from my service. Which is a bit of a shame as I may need to for classes that call a couple of service methods for data before doing the "work" on that data. If that makes sense. Never mind, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's something weird going on in your mock setup. I think the matching parameters that you setup are restricted to the first layer of function calls. You might need to do something like:

```
mockClientProxy.Setup(m => m.Execute(It.IsAny<Expression<Action<TChannel>>>())).Callback(RemoveItem);
```

Moq works by implementing the methods on the interface of its argument, in this case it's the interface methods of `IWcfClientProxy<ITestingServiceInterface>`. So when you setup the method call to Execute, you need to setup the matching parameters for the arguments to Execute. What you've done in your code is to setup a match for that specific delegate function, which would never actually match anything because you don't store it and call Execute with it later.